# How to block light using a plane with holes in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a cube who has an emission node as material. I want to use a plane with a hole to let the camera only look through that hole.

Ideally, the light-blocking plane should act as a perfect "light blocker" that does nothing but allows light to only go through its hole. That is, I don't want it to contribute any reflections etc.

Simply using a black (because my background is black) diffuse shader *looks* OK, but my application (for research) requires an ideal light blocker.

[image]

---

Here's my .blend file (500KB).

[image]

Comment: Instead of a black background and a black object you can use a transparent background and a [holdout shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/holdout.html?highlight=holdout). Everything will be transparent but the light that shines through the hole, and there will be no light reflected back to the scene. Then you can composite that over any background you need.

Comment: @cegaton sounds legit -- thanks! What if I simply don't use any background node, not enable alpha channel, and meanwhile use holdout shaders? Does this combination make sense?